# If I give a user table privileges do i need to give them a database role as well

Tags: oracle, security, sqlplus, user-roles, database-security

I have a database and want to give out roles and privileges.

My aim is to allow multiple users - all have the same privileges - to be able to create, edit and view the tables (That's it).

I understand there are user table privileges that allow a user to `Create, alter, drop and delete` items in tables. But I also understand that there is a 
`resource user` pre-defined role that allows a user to do the same thing.

Would I offer both of the roles? The table-level privileges and predefined roles? What would happen if I do offer both? Can I?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "alter" and "drop" in this context?  `alter` and `drop` are DDL commands that let you modify the structure of a table or remove the table from the database.  Those are not object-level permissions and do not relate to rows in the table.  Do you really mean "select, insert, update, and delete rows in a table"?

Comment: Different database products have different ways they organize things. In Oracle, each user owns a "schema" (all the tables, indexes, procedures, etc. they created themselves). A user is generally (but not always!) granted extensive privileges to their own schema, and very few privileges to other people's schemas. **Where** do you want "all" users to be able to edit and view tables? Each in their own schema, or do you want to create a "general" schema for "general" objects, and give users privileges on objects in that schema only?

Comment: But if i offer a resource user role to a user, wouldn't that allow the user to alter all the tables on the database?

Comment: Allowing a user to alter all the tables is a huge security risk.  Why in the world would you even _think_ of allowing that to anyone but a DBA?

Comment: To be honest, the question was more of a 'can I' - like would it even make a different kind of question (or even should I). I just found it strange why there are roles and table privileges, so if I offer a resource user role to a user, wouldn't that allow the user to alter all the tables on the database, then what's the point of even having table-level privileges?

Comment: @JustinCave: I fell for the same confustion about alter and drop, but that is the description of the resource role in the 2d DBA guide: "Enables a user to create, modify, and delete certain types of schema objects in the schema associated with that user"

Comment: @wolφi - Are you asking about the privileges associated with the predefined role `resource` (which should not be used in a real system)?  Because that does contain a variety of system privileges which allow you to do things like create and drop tables in your own schema.  It does not grant object-level privileges that would allow you to insert or delete rows in someone else's table.

Comment: @JustinCave: no, I think it's a documentation bug. The word `DELETE` does not make sense in the description of the role `RESOURCE` in the [2 day DBA guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/admqs/administering-user-accounts-and-security.html#GUID-289A4BF6-F703-4ED5-8357-89F651A6D1DE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is more a database administration question, as you have users that develop their own tables. And the heart of your question, "one size fits all prepacked" role `RESOURCE` or better a bespoke solution for your set of users is really one of administrative style, taste, and your special case.

Personally, I don't like the role `RESOURCE` as it lacks the privilege `CREATE VIEW`.

Please note that the privilege `CREATE TABLE` (granted directly or via a role) allows the user to create tables in his/her own schema. To create tables in other schemas (or "all the tables on the database"), you need the privilege `CREATE ANY TABLE`. See [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/GRANT.html#GUID-20B4E2C0-A7F8-4BC8-A5E8-BE61BDC41AC3) for details.